# Unity3D controls in Blender

Tags: 3d-view, customization

I am used to the control setup in Unity (moving around the world/scene) and I would like to use the same controls in Blender. How can I import these settings without changing them all manually. I tried, but failed and had to reset the controls.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to User preferences > Input and set Presets(drop down menu to the top left and another one to right) to Maya.

[image]

It's been a long time since I've used Unity, but I think Unity and Maya are very similar in this aspect.

If Maya is not similar, try the 3DsMax preset.

Comment: Unfortunately both presets are still very different from Unity.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution, just import configuration: https://gist.github.com/bitinn/22f6fefe026d8d9e83468864edb8f835

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a git repo that cover this, I'll give it a try as well.

https://github.com/niusounds/Blender-Keyconfig